# When will the Nvidia Vulkan driver arrive in Additional Drivers?

Tags: 14.04, drivers, nvidia, proprietary, vulkan

I'm looking forward to trying the new Vulkan API with some of my games. But I also like to stick with the fully tested, Ubuntu-approved drivers provided in Additional Drivers.

Given that Nvidia driver version 367.18 just came out on May 23rd, 2016, about how long will it take for it to show up fully tested in the Additional Drivers on Ubuntu?

(I'm on Ubuntu 14.04.4 by the way, if that makes a difference.)

Thanks!

Comment: Additional drivers are proprietary drivers. It's not up to Ubuntu/Canonical to decide when. You should ask nVidia about the testing program, should you volunteer for that.

Comment: Hey there, I was just wondering how long it generally takes the Ubuntu team to fully test and approve the latest Nvidia drivers (weeks, months?), and for them to add them to their available driver repository. I know that they're proprietary; didn't mean to sound misleading about that.

Comment: I really don't know.  Some driver versions get approved,  other don't because they aren't stable enough. It could be months or never.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every Ubuntu edition ships with the latest current stable NVIDIA drivers from the NVIDIA long-lived branch. These drivers are tested, maintained and provided with security updates until the end of life of this edition is reached. Newer NVIDIA drivers releases are not added, but they are made available from the Proprietary GPU Drivers PPA. Every time new drivers are released they are getting added shortly, in most of the cases this happens within one or two days. When you want to install more current drivers, add this PPA to the software sources. Just open a terminal and execute the following command : `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa`. Update the repositories : `sudo apt update`. Now you can see new drivers in Additional Drivers.

Comment: Alright, thank you! That was exactly what I needed to know.

Comment: Just an additional question, if you're still on here. I've added the Nvidia driver repository you mentioned, but don't see the new Vulkan driver (367.18) listed. Is this because it is still in beta? Will it be added a day or two after it's out of beta?

Comment: @sunnybubblegum : NVIDIA drivers 367.18 are available for Ubuntu 16.04 from the PPA since 2016-05-19, but they are not available for Ubuntu 14.04 because the new LTS edition 16.04 was released in April ... so when you want to use these drivers, you should upgrade the system - or better - make a clean and fresh installation of Ubuntu 16.04 LTS ! :) Reference : https://launchpad.net/~graphics-drivers/+archive/ubuntu/ppa

Comment: Aw. I'm unable to use Ubuntu 16.04 because my WiFi network adapter is not supported in kernels later than 3.13 (and I really want to have Internet on my computer). Oh well. Maybe once it is (hopefully one day) supported, I can upgrade to 16.04 and use the Vulkan driver. Anyway, thanks for your clarification!